# How to get the selected "Person Type" (user or group) from the Microsoft Graph Toolkit People Picker control in javascript?

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-toolkit

The javascript Microsoft Graph Toolkit people picker control has an event called "SelectionChanged" that is raised when a user or group is selected in the people picker. It also has a property called "selectedPeople" that list the users and groups that have been selected. Both the event and the property return an array of IDynamicPerson objects.

The problem that I have is that I cannot find a way to distinguih between users and groups. The IDynamicPerson interface does not offer a property to distinguish them. Does anyone knows how to distinguish the users from the groups on the returned IDynamicPerson array?

Answer (score 0):

From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker#cache), there is `personType` property which you can use to distinquish

Something like this when handling the event.

```
const handleSelectionChanged = (event) => {
const selectedPeople = event.detail;

const selectedUsers = selectedPeople.filter((person) => person.personType === "User");
const selectedGroups = selectedPeople.filter((person) => person.personType === "Group");

// Now you have separate arrays for selected users and groups.
console.log("Selected Users:", selectedUsers);
console.log("Selected Groups:", selectedGroups);
```

};

```
document.querySelector('mgt-people-picker').addEventListener('selectionChanged', handleSelectionChanged);
```